# Driver installation: compiling source code for newer kernel

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, compatibility

I am trying to install a driver for this [DAQ card](http://support.advantech.com/support/DownloadSRDetail.aspx?SR_ID=1-41GHVV&Doc_Source=Download), but when I execute (as in given documentation):

```
insmod /usr/.../advdrv_core.ko
```

**i get this error:**

```
invalid module format
```

As I found out, this is because downloaded driver is for kernel 2.6.18, so it will not work on new one, but there is also source code provided so is it possible to compile it for this kernel?

Comment: "Compiling from source code" isn't a very descriptive sentence for this question. Could you change to one more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

If the kernel module is outdated (and doesn't work with the newest kernels) then just having the source code does not mean that you can just compile it. It would need to be modified at the source level to be made compatible with newer kernels.

The link you provided doesn't load for me, so I can't really say much about the company/etc., but I would suggest contacting who ever made the kernel module and requesting that they modify it to work with the newer kernels.

Comment: I have contacted Advantech but thay told me just that - "I can try to compile it" :(