# How (recipe) to build only one kernel module?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel, compiling, source-code

I have a bug in a Linux kernel module that causes the stock Ubuntu 14.04 kernel to oops (crash).

That is why I want to **edit**/**patch** the source of only that **single kernel module** to add some extra debug output. The kernel module in question is `mvsas` and not necessary to boot. For that reason I don't see any need to update any initrd images.

I have read a lot of information (as shown below) and find the setup and build process confusion. I need two recipes:

1. to setup/configure the build environment once
2. steps to do after editing any source file of this kernel module (`.c` and `.h`) and converting that edit into a new kernel module (`.ko`)

---

The sources that have been used are:

- build one kernel module - Google search
- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/rebuilding-a-single-kernel-module-595116/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744087/how-to-recompile-just-a-single-kernel-module
- http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/rebuild_kernel_module.html
- [How do I build a single in-tree kernel module?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168279/how-do-i-build-a-single-in-tree-kernel-module)
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1153067
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2112166
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1115593
- build one kernel module ubuntu - Google search
- 'make +single +kernel +module' - Ask Ubuntu
- 'make +kernel +module' - Ask Ubuntu
- [My makefile results in: No rule to make target `arch/x86/tools/relocs.c', needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232840/trouble-compiling-a-kernel-module-in-linux/266886#266886)
- '"Invalid module format"' - Ask Ubuntu
- [Driver installation: compiling source code for newer kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14382/driver-installation-compiling-source-code-for-newer-kernel)
- [Modprobe: 'Invalid nodule format', yet works after insmod](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490616/ubuntu-trouble-with-modprobe-invalid-module-format-yet-works-after-insmod)
- "Symbol version dump" "is missing" - Google search
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425523/should-i-care-that-the-symbol-version-dump-is-missing-how-do-i-get-one
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/369051/where-can-i-find-the-corresponding-module-symvers-and-config-files-for-ubutunu
- ["no symbol version for module_layout" when trying to load usbhid.ko](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14627/no-symbol-version-for-module-layout-when-trying-to-load-usbhid-ko/171633#171633)
- [Broken links inside Linux header file folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272234/broken-links-inside-linux-header-file-folder)
- 'make modules_install' - Ask Ubuntu
- 'modules_install' - Ask Ubuntu
- [Empty build directory in custom compiled kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437465/empty-build-directory-in-custom-compiled-kernel/437469#437469)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/444345/not-able-to-see-pr-info-output
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/472496/in-which-directory-are-the-kernel-source-files-and-how-can-i-recompile-it
- [How can I compile and install that patched libata-eh.c file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132146/how-can-i-compile-and-install-that-patched-libata-eh-c-file/137223#137223)
- 'modules_install +depmod' - Ask Ubuntu
- modules_install depmod - Google search
- "make modules_install" - Google search
- http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/CMSC421/fall02/burt/projects/howto_build_kernel.html
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20864/what-happens-in-each-step-of-the-linux-kernel-building-process
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelCustomBuild
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/build-linux-kernel-module-against-installed-kernel-source-tree.html
- http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/kernel/170617-solved-make-modules_install-different-path.html
- "make prepare" - Google search
- "make prepare" "scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig" - Google search
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1963515
- ubuntu "make prepare" version - Google search
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276245/how-to-compile-a-kernel-module-against-a-new-source
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile
- [How do I compile a kernel module?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51743/how-do-i-compile-a-kernel-module)
- [How to add a custom driver to my kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186855/how-to-add-a-custom-driver-to-my-kernel)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/426549/compile-and-loading-kernel-module-without-compiling-the-kernel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I build a single in-tree kernel module?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168279/how-do-i-build-a-single-in-tree-kernel-module)

Comment: perhaps this article will help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744087/how-to-recompile-just-a-single-kernel-module/44204152#44204152

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The recipe to build a custom module might need to be split in three sections.

### Setup once

```
$ cd ~
$ apt-get source linux-source-3.13.0
```

I am too lazy to copy the mvsas specific driver source files; just copy them all to your current working directory. If `apt-get` results in an error message about *missing source URIs* then see note #4 at the bottom.

```
$ cd linux-3.13.0
$ make oldconfig
$ make prepare
$ make scripts
```

This will prepare some files necessary to build a kernel module.

### Each kernel version

```
$ apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

This will install headers and the Ubuntu kernel configuration file for that kernel version in /lib/modules.

```
$ cd ~/linux-3.13.0
$ cp -v /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers .
```

This to prevent the message "*no symbol version for module_layout*" when loading the module with insmod or modprobe.

```
$ mv -v /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/scsi/mvsas/mvsas.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/scsi/mvsas/mvsas.ko.backup
```

This will rename the original (Ubuntu build) kernel module to make sure that the custom patched one will load.

### Each edit

```
$ cd ~/linux-3.13.0/drivers/scsi/mvsas
$ nano mv_sas.h
$ nano mv_sas.c
```

These are for the edits.

```
$ make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
```

This will compile and build the kernel module `.ko` file using the kernel configuration from your stock Ubuntu distribution as stored in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/`.

```
$ make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules_install
```

This will install the kernel module in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/extra/`, not overwriting the distribution module in case you didn't rename the distribution kernel module file. In this mvsas case it will also run [depmod](http://linux.die.net/man/8/depmod).

```
$ lsmod | grep mvsas
```

If this results in any output, the mvsas module needs unloading with (`modprobe -r mvsas`) first.

```
$ sudo modprobe -v mvsas
```

This should load the new kernel module.

Check the output to verify that `/lib/modules/.../extra/mvsas.ko` is being loaded.

#### Modprobe error: could not insert

In some cases you might experience a `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'xyz': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)` while in the verbose modprobe output you see that `insmod` is trying to load the module from the kernel default location. For example:

```
# insmod /lib/modules/3.17.0-031700rc7-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/pm8001/pm80xx.ko
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'pm80xx': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

In that case you need to manually run [depmod](http://linux.die.net/man/8/depmod) and try to load the module again:

```
# depmod
# sudo modprobe -v mvsas
```

#### Notes

1. It may be the case that the resulting `.ko` module files are much (for example 20 times) larger in size than the original module files as distributed by Ubuntu; in that case the `make prepare` step could have created a Linux developers debugging kernel configuration file and you are building from the source directory. Your `-C` param might not function as expected.
2. I have seen guides with other commands like `make modules_prepare` and `make M=scripts/mod` but I don't think these are necessary for this case.
3. You can use the Linux developers debug config by replacing `-C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build` with `-C /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
4. In a default setup, `apt-get source linux-sources` will return error `E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`. To fix this issue you can modify file `/etc/apt/sources.list` by uncommenting (removing the leading `#` from) the first `deb-src` line. Example for Ubuntu 17.10: `deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted`. run `sudo apt-get update`, and then the command will deliver sources for you. See also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list) where a GUI method for doing this is described too.

Comment: I got error: /bin/sh: arm-none-linux -gnueabi-gcc: not found

Comment: `$(uname-r)` is apparently wrong... You need to call the `shell` built-in: `$(shell uname -r)`

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I also see [cases where `$(shell uname -r)` doesn't work](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1834273). Why is `$(uname -r)` so apparently wrong?

Comment: I had to also call `echo "search extra built-in" | sudo tee /etc/depmod.d/00-extra.conf` so that `depmod` sees the newly updated file in `.../extra`.

Comment: What to do with module signing error, how to avoid it? 
``` 
INSTALL /home/envek/linux-4.10.0/drivers/hwmon/dell-smm-hwmon.ko
At main.c:158:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I get this when I try to build the `radeon` module: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093718/radeon-trace-h-no-such-file-or-directory-when-trying-to-build-radeon

Comment: I have sorted out the problem above. Now I'm stuck here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1135475/632192

Comment: This didn't work for building the multiple ko's in drivers/media/v4l2-core because some non-linux-header include dirs are not added to compilation. Doing the following in the root of the source dir makes it work:
sudo make SUBDIRS=drivers/media/v4l2-core modules

Comment: works until this line : `$ make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules_install`, get a lot of errors `sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory` even if cert files have been created with https://superuser.com/a/1322832
.
Seems that it searches `certs` directory from local dir (in my case `drivers/hwmon`) instead of from `linux-5.8.0` folder

Comment: Also `../crypto/bio` folder is missing => `SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76`. Can you help to fix this please ?

Comment: To fix the crypto problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/820883/how-to-resolve-ssl-error-during-make-modules-install-command