# Hauppauge WinTV-soloHD usb stick does not work on 16.04.1

Tags: tv-tuner

This question has been extensively discussed under the 'Hauppauge winTv SoloHD unclaimed' 1 question on askubuntu.

My set up is similar.

andrew@xps15:~$ lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
andrew@xps15:~$ uname -a
Linux xps15 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
me-tv using Hauppauge WinTV-soloHD usb stick
There are no DVB devices available
```

andrew@xps15:~$ lsusb

```
              *-usb:0 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: soloHD
                   vendor: HCW
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 1.00
                   serial: 0011529330
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

andrew@xps15:~$ lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:21d5 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:6410 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2b95 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2040:0264 Hauppauge 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

andrew@xps15:~$ dmesg

```
[ 3023.784687] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 3023.913568] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2040, idProduct=0264
[ 3023.913570] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[ 3023.913572] usb 1-1: Product: soloHD
[ 3023.913573] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HCW
[ 3023.913574] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 0011529330
```

At this point the answer to the question on askubuntu begins to become very complicated in my opinion. I have the required drivers in /lib/firmware but I have not followed the 'build and make v4l-dvb' thread; its just a bit too much for me - sorry.
So my question is:
Is there another way to solve my problem?
Thanks
Andrew

Comment: If you actually have a linux-compatible driver for your SPECIFIC device, you'll need to learn how to do the `make` and `sudo make install` steps. Follow the steps in the `readme` or `install` files normally included with the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a separate driver for your hardware like shown here: [How (recipe) to build only one kernel module?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515407/how-recipe-to-build-only-one-kernel-module).
No need to build all modules for dvb.