# How to build wil6210 driver from source code from Git

Tags: drivers, compiling, git, additional-drivers

I want to build and install `wil6210` drive which is in the Linux upstream. I have managed to download the source from [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/ath/wil6210). The folder contains `Makefile` and another file named `Kconfig`. When I try to make it says: `make: *** No targets.  Stop.` I tried using different config files but they did not work. Here is the result:

```
elans@elans-TravelMate-P446-M:~/linux-source/wil6210$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
elans@elans-TravelMate-P446-M:~/linux-source/wil6210$ ./Kconfig
bash: ./Kconfig: Permission denied
elans@elans-TravelMate-P446-M:~/linux-source/wil6210$ sudo ./Kconfig
sudo: ./Kconfig: command not found
elans@elans-TravelMate-P446-M:~/linux-source/wil6210$ make
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Here is the content of the `Makefile`:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
obj-$(CONFIG_WIL6210) += wil6210.o

wil6210-y := main.o
wil6210-y += netdev.o
wil6210-y += cfg80211.o
wil6210-y += pcie_bus.o
wil6210-$(CONFIG_WIL6210_DEBUGFS) += debugfs.o
wil6210-y += wmi.o
wil6210-y += interrupt.o
wil6210-y += txrx.o
wil6210-y += debug.o
wil6210-y += rx_reorder.o
wil6210-y += fw.o
wil6210-y += pm.o
wil6210-y += pmc.o
wil6210-$(CONFIG_WIL6210_TRACING) += trace.o
wil6210-y += wil_platform.o
wil6210-y += ethtool.o
wil6210-y += wil_crash_dump.o
wil6210-y += p2p.o

# for tracing framework to find trace.h
CFLAGS_trace.o := -I$(src)
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: You can't compile kernel modules like that. If you want a module that's in a more recent kernel version than your current one, you must upgrade your kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compile only a specific module form the kernel source code you need the following command. Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515407/how-recipe-to-build-only-one-kernel-module)

Basically you need to `cd` to wil6210 code directory and run the following command:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
```

Make sure to change the `$(uname -r)` to your target kernel version, i.e. the kernel version of the system you want your wil6210 module to work on