# amdgpu_trace.h: No such file or directory When trying to build amdgpu

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, make, amdgpu

The full error message from `make`:

```
In file included from /home/username/linux-5.0.0/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_trace.h:496,
             from /home/username/linux-5.0.0/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_trace_points.c:29:
./include/trace/define_trace.h:89:42: fatal error: ../../drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_trace.h: No such file or directory
 #include TRACE_INCLUDE(TRACE_INCLUDE_FILE)
                                          ^
compilation terminated.
```

(replace `username` with my home folder name above)

I've been trying to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515407/how-recipe-to-build-only-one-kernel-module) to modify, build, and insert the `amdgpu` module into the already built kernel without having to build the whole kernel as I do always because of [this bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105664).

It happens when I run `make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules` from the directory `~/linux-4.18.0/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/`.

Comment: I have the same problem. Please answer your own question if you solved it.

Comment: @Flip I haven't solved my question. I will try your solution asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `amdgpu_trace.h` file, and change the line:

```
#define TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH ../../drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu
```

to

```
#define TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH ../../../../../drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu
```