# radeon_trace.h: No such file or directory when trying to build radeon module

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, radeon, amd-graphics

The full error message from make:

```
    In file included from /home/huexxx/ubuntu-modules/linux-5.8.0/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_trace.h:209,
                 from /home/huexxx/ubuntu-modules/linux-5.8.0/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_trace_points.c:10:
./include/trace/define_trace.h:95:42: fatal error: ../../drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_trace.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
   95 | #include TRACE_INCLUDE(TRACE_INCLUDE_FILE)
      |                                          ^
compilation terminated.
```

I've been trying to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515407/how-recipe-to-build-only-one-kernel-module) to modify, build, and insert the radeon module into the already built kernel without having to build the whole kernel as I do always in order to reduce compiling time.

It happens when I run `make -C /lib/modules/5.8.0-31-generic/build M=$(pwd)/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon modules` from the directory `/home/huexxx/ubuntu-modules/linux-5.8.0`

I've already searched a solution to this, and there are precedents for the same problem like you can see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093718/amdgpu-trace-h-no-such-file-or-directory-when-trying-to-build-amdgpu). The proposed solution is to add two (in this case acording to path depth)  `../` to correct on `radeon_trace.h` the relative path to add to `TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH`, but it doesn't work with any number of `../` added... I've tried all the possibilities...

```
./include/trace/define_trace.h:95:42: fatal error: ../../../../drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_trace.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio

./include/trace/define_trace.h:95:42: fatal error: ../../../../../drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_trace.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio

./include/trace/define_trace.h:95:42: fatal error: ../../../drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_trace.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio

./include/trace/define_trace.h:95:42: fatal error: ../drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_trace.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio

./include/trace/define_trace.h:95:42: fatal error: ./drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_trace.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio

./include/trace/define_trace.h:95:42: fatal error: drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_trace.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio

./include/trace/define_trace.h:95:42: fatal error: /drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_trace.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
```

(yeah, it's stupid to try nonsense abslute paths... but is due to desesperation).

Then, I've tried to use absolute path... but `linux` is replaced by `1`...

```
./include/trace/define_trace.h:95:42: fatal error: /home/huexxx/ubuntu-modules/1-5.8.0/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_trace.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
```

Then, in a last effort... I've renamed linux-5.8.0 folder to lin-5.8.0 to avoid the replacing problem... and it finally works!

```
LD [M]  /home/huexxx/ubuntu-modules/lin-5.8.0/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko
```

Well... the reason of the post is to know:

- Why the compile doesn't directly work, because the addition of ../../ on the path is a well known patch to drivers' code.
- Why the compile doesn't work modifying the relative path in any way... the file should be there in one of the possibilities.
- Why `linux` is replaced by `1` if I put it in the absolute path.

Best regards.

Comment: Why are you trying yo build radeon module. It is already built in the kernel.

Comment: In order to patch the driver to unlock the TMDS-pixelclock.

In my old HD 6870 it's limited to 165MHz using HDMI, and with the patch I can get 2560x1440 at 60Hz, while with stock driver it's limited to 1920x1080 60Hz.

You can get more info here:

https://www.elstel.org/software/hunt-for-4K-UHD-2160p.html.en

https://euphi.github.io/2017/12/31/UHD-Monitor-Linux.html

Let me know if you need more info.